# error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools"

Tags: python-3.x

При попытке установить модуль cld2-cffi. Я устанавливаю с помощью команды `pip install cld2-cffi`, появляется ошибка `error: [WinError 3] Системе не удается найти указанный путь: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\lib'`. Изначально ее там не было. Я ее сам добавил. Появился вот такой длинный стек ошибки. Я не знаю, что тут полезно, а что нет, поэтому вот весь стек:

```
D:\Minicanoda3\Scripts>pip install cld2-cffi
Collecting cld2-cffi
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/6d/044789e730141bcda2a7368836f714684a7d13bd44a2a33b387cb31b433
5/cld2-cffi-0.1.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\cld2_cffi.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\cld2_cffi.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\cld2_cffi.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info\cld2_cffi.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\cld2_cffi.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\cld2_cffi.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    _cffi__x8075a5eex25bdf976.c
    d:\minicanoda3\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: ?? г¤ ?вбп RвЄалвм д c< ўЄ<оз?-Ё?: io.h: No such file or d
irectory,
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 382, in compile
        self.spawn(args)
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 501, in spawn
        return super().spawn(cmd)
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
        spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 38, in spawn
        _spawn_nt(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 81, in _spawn_nt
        "command %r failed with exit status %d" % (cmd, rc))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\
\Tools\\MSVC\\14.13.26128\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\cffi\ffiplatform.py", line 49, in _build
        dist.run_command('build_ext')
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 78, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 199, in build_extension
        _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 533, in build_extension
        depends=ext.depends)
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 384, in compile
        raise CompileError(msg)
    distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools
\\MSVC\\14.13.26128\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\0DDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dg0cixwd\cld2-cffi\setup.py", line 191, in <module>
        'Topic :: Text Processing :: Linguistic'
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 278, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 293, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 524, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 560, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\py36compat.py", line 34, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_python()
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 127, in _add_defaults_python
        build_py = self.get_finalized_command('build_py')
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line 34, in finalize_options
        orig.build_py.finalize_options(self)
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\command\build_py.py", line 45, in finalize_options
        ('force', 'force'))
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 287, in set_undefined_options
        src_cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "C:\Users\0DDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dg0cixwd\cld2-cffi\setup.py", line 143, in finalize_options
        self.distribution.ext_modules = get_ext_modules()
      File "C:\Users\0DDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dg0cixwd\cld2-cffi\setup.py", line 128, in get_ext_modules
        import cld2
      File "C:\Users\0DDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dg0cixwd\cld2-cffi\cld2\__init__.py", line 190, in <module>
        extra_compile_args=_COMPILER_ARGS)
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 438, in verify
        lib = self.verifier.load_library()
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\cffi\verifier.py", line 114, in load_library
        self._compile_module()
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\cffi\verifier.py", line 211, in _compile_module
        outputfilename = ffiplatform.compile(tmpdir, self.get_extension())
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\cffi\ffiplatform.py", line 20, in compile
        outputfilename = _build(tmpdir, ext, compiler_verbose, debug)
      File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\cffi\ffiplatform.py", line 56, in _build
        raise VerificationError('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
    cffi.error.VerificationError: CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Communi
ty\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.13.26128\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: файл io.h не найден

Comment: Так, это же стандартная библиотека и такого быть не должно. Или нет?

Comment: У вас винда, питон, и визуал студио одинаковой разрядности ?

Comment: "Изначально ее там не было. Я ее сам добавил." Поясните

Comment: К слову у меня виндовс 8 питон 3.6.0 и библиотека установилась без проблем 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Communi
ty\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.13.26128\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe' помоему x86 и x64 вещи не совместимые