# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polyglot.detect'; 'polyglot' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Есть код:

```
from polyglot.detect import Detector
arabic_text = u"""
أفاد مصدر امني في قيادة عمليات صلاح الدين في العراق بأن " القوات الامنية تتوقف لليوم
الثالث على التوالي عن التقدم الى داخل مدينة تكريت بسبب
انتشار قناصي التنظيم الذي يطلق على نفسه اسم "الدولة الاسلامية" والعبوات الناسفة
والمنازل المفخخة والانتحاريين، فضلا عن ان القوات الامنية تنتظر وصول تعزيزات اضافية ".
"""
Detector = Detector(arabic_text)
print(Detector.language)
```

Он полностью был взят из документации на сайте: `http://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Detection.html`
Но что-то идет не так. 
Я пробовал установить cld2, подробности тут:

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815085/error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-get-it-with-microsoft-visual-c
```

Оказалось, не установлен git. Установив git, появилась ошибка:

```
Invalid requirement: 'git+github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git@master'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.0-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 93, in __init
__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.0-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1632, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.0-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1622, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.0-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.0-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3395, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.0-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1383, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.0-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3183, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected stringEnd (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.0-py3.6.egg\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 252, in from_line
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.0-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 97, in __init
__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'+github.'"
```

Comment: Ну вот не понятно, то ли проблема в том, что не получается установить pyicu или проблема в коде выше

Comment: "Но что-то идет не так." - что именно?

Comment: Как файл вообще называется? Не ``polyglot.py`` ли?

Comment: Появляется ошибка. Да, все началось с установки библиотеки polyglot

Comment: Файл, в котором код, как называется?

Comment: ``import polyglot``, ``print (polyglot.__file__)`` что выдает?

Comment: D:\perforce\Social\polyglot.py
D:\perforce\Social\polyglot.py

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Переименуйте и никогда больше не называйте свои файлы названиями библиотек.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что ТС изменил смысл вопроса после того, как ему был дан ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка из-за того, что файл, из которого запускается код, сам называется `polyglot.py`. Или где-то в папке из системной переменной `path` (список папок можно посмотреть по `print sys.path`) лежит такой файл, созданный пользователем. И строчка `import polyglot.detect` импортирует именно его, а не библиотеку. А в нем  нет никаких модулей `detect` и `Detector`.

Избежать таких ошибок очень просто - никогда не называть собственные файлы именем библиотек.

Answer (score 1):

При попытке установить `polyglot` на Windows 7 (64-bit) обычным способом:

```
pip install polyglot
```

установка проходит успешно, но при попытке импорта вылетает с ошибкой:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycld2'

Попробуйте установить последнюю версию polyglot на Windows так:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git@master
```

---

```
(ml) C:\Users\Max>pip install -U git+https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git@master
Collecting git+https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git@master
  Cloning https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git (to master) to d:\temp\pip-a_7e1rgb-build
Requirement already up-to-date: PyICU>=1.8 in c:\users\max\anaconda3_5.0\envs\ml\lib\site-packages (from polyglot==16.7.4)
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel>=0.23.0 in c:\users\max\anaconda3_5.0\envs\ml\lib\site-packages (from polyglot==16.7.4)
Requirement already up-to-date: pycld2>=0.3 in c:\users\max\anaconda3_5.0\envs\ml\lib\site-packages (from polyglot==16.7.4)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.7.3 in c:\users\max\anaconda3_5.0\envs\ml\lib\site-packages (from polyglot==16.7.4)
Collecting futures>=2.1.6 (from polyglot==16.7.4)
Requirement already up-to-date: morfessor>=2.0.2a1 in c:\users\max\anaconda3_5.0\envs\ml\lib\site-packages (from polyglot==16.7.4)

Collecting numpy>=1.6.1 (from polyglot==16.7.4)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/70/cd94a1655d082b8f024b21af1eb13dd0f3035ffe78ff43d4ff9bb97baa5f/numpy-1.1
4.2-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl (13.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 13.4MB 34kB/s
Installing collected packages: futures, numpy, polyglot
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.12.1
    Uninstalling numpy-1.12.1:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.12.1
  Running setup.py install for polyglot ... done
Successfully installed futures-3.1.1 numpy-1.14.2 polyglot-16.7.4
```

Тест:

```
In [1]: %paste
from polyglot.detect import Detector
arabic_text = u"""
أفاد مصدر امني في قيادة عمليات صلاح الدين في العراق بأن " القوات الامنية تتوقف لل
الثالث على التوالي عن التقدم الى داخل مدينة تكريت بسبب
انتشار قناصي التنظيم الذي يطلق على نفسه اسم "الدولة الاسلامية" والعبوات الناسفة
والمنازل المفخخة والانتحاريين، فضلا عن ان القوات الامنية تنتظر وصول تعزيزات اضافي
"""
Detector = Detector(arabic_text)
print(Detector.language)

## -- End pasted text --
name: Arabisch    code: ar       confidence:  99.0 read bytes:   907
```

Comment: Попробовал получил ошибку:   Error [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/aboSamoor/p
olyglot.git C:\Users\0DDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-l_sxilca
Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?

Comment: Загуглил ошибку, толком ничего не нашел

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov, http://www.techoism.com/how-to-install-git-bash-on-windows/

Comment: установил. Видимо, нужно сделать что-то еще

Comment: git установлен.