# Необходимо создать приложение для определения тональности предложения на основе polyglot

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо найти главное слово и его тональность

документация тут: http://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Sentiment.html

Я написал код:

```
from polyglot.downloader import downloader
print(downloader.supported_languages_table("sentiment2", 3))

from polyglot.text import Text

blob = ("В целях возрождения традиций написания сочинения как самостоятельной творческой работы Министерством образования и науки Российской Федерации ежегодно проводится Всероссийский конкурс сочинений"
        "RКонкурс проходит в  этапа школьный муниципальный региональный и всероссийский по  возрастным группам обучающиеся  классов обучающиеся  классов обучающиеся  классов студенты профессиональных образовательных организаций")
text = Text(blob)

print("{:<16}{}".format("Word", "Polarity")+"\n"+"-"*30)
for w in text.words:
    print("{:<16}{:>2}".format(w, w.polarity))
```

Даже не новичок...

Я получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/perforce/Social/test1.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(downloader.supported_languages_table("sentiment2", 3))
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\polyglot\downloader.py", line 978, in supported_languages_table
    languages = self.supported_languages(task)
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\polyglot\downloader.py", line 970, in supported_languages
    collection = self.get_collection(task=task)
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\polyglot\downloader.py", line 946, in get_collection
    return self.info(id)
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\polyglot\downloader.py", line 929, in info
    self._update_index() # If package is not found, most probably we did not
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\polyglot\downloader.py", line 843, in _update_index
    P = Package.fromcsobj(p)
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\polyglot\downloader.py", line 216, in fromcsobj
    language = subdir.split(path.sep)[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Необходимо найти главное слово и его тональность. В коде ошибка. Я не понимаю, что идет не так

Comment: Необходимо исправить ошибку

Comment: Судя по ошибке, все что ниже `print(downloader.supported_languages_table("sentiment2", 3))` к вопросу отношения не имеет. Автор, сами убедитесь в этом, закомментировав тот код. Если я прав, удалите из вопроса ненужный код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по ошибкам в репозитории [polyglot](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot):

- https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/12
- https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/32
- https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/58

Эта ошибка `IndexError: list index out of range` только в `Windows` происходит.

Сам [автор написал](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/32#issuecomment-152231474), что не планировал поддерживать `Windows`:

> There is no plan to support windows. I tested the software on linux
> and it worked fine.

---

Почему так происходит и как решить я уже не буду, т.к. **MaxU** дал на это [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818683/201445)

---

Кст, проблема была исправлена в этом [коммите](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/commit/91027e333ef6e509de4f5ac707d790df7e8eb1be#diff-0c75843ec4defe1b895aed0cba59f751), но, видимо, не попала в репозиторий [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/polyglot/), поэтому `pip install polyglot` установит версию с той багой.

Можно установить самую свежую версию напрямую из репозитория `polyglot`:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git@master
```

Answer (score 2):

Это [баг, который "ломает" код под Windows](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/12). Чтобы починить надо изменить код в `polyglot\downloader.py` с:

```
language = subdir.split(path.sep)[1]
```

на:

```
language = subdir.split('/')[1]
```

или [установить исправленную версию polyglot с GitHub](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/815157/211923)